# jQuery treeview wont work in async mode

Tags: jquery, treeview

ive downloaded a treeview plugin for jquery (from http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/) and ive got a problem with it, because it doesnt generate anything visible.

Ive generated a json string with php:

```
[{"text": "RSS feed"}, 
 {"text": "Documents", children: [{"text": "test.txt"}]}, 
 {"text": "Todo lists"}]
```

The jquery code looks like this:

```
$("#baskets_tree").treeview({collapsed:false,url: "http://localhost/json.php?q=baskets"});
```

and of course the file contains a list:

```
<ul id="baskets_tree"></ul>
```

Everything is loaded, the json code is requested, and nothing changes on the screen.
So what could be the problem with this? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you inspected the AJAX request and response? FireBug is great for this: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Yep, ive tested it, and it works :) i've copied the json from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a new version of jQuery (1.4+) [it'll silently fail because your JSON is invalid](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/308d6cdad023da190ace2a698ee4815ed8dad9c5), check it here: http://www.jsonlint.com/

The issue is that the `children` property needs double quotes as well, like this:

```
[{"text": "RSS feed"}, 
 {"text": "Documents", "children": [{"text": "test.txt"}]}, 
 {"text": "Todo lists"}]
```

I can't say if you have any *other* issues of course, but that's a sure show stopper and one that needs fixing if you're on jQuery 1.4+, see if that resolve the issue or gets you further along.